# Configure Lotus Notes to ask for password before sending mails?

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there any setting related to my question or is there any way to configure Lotus Notes to only receive mails but not send mails.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying that there's no simple way to do this.

You would need two identities -- i.e., two Notes ID files. (These are normally supplied by your Notes administrators.) I.e., one for "Rajat Saxena/MyCompany" and one for "Rajat Saxena/NoMail".

You would need your /MyCompany identity to delegate access to your mailbox to your /NoMail identity.

You would need two location documents, one for each identity.  The one for your /MyCompany identity would be set up normally, and the one for your /NoMail identity would be set up with no mailfile and mailserver information.  The location documents would each specify automatic switching to the appropriate ID file.

When you want to only receive, you would switch to your /NoMail location, which would propmpt you for one password. When you want to send, you would have to first switch to your /MyCompany identity, which would prompt you for another password.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for a single user or a group You could alter the ACL in the server mail.box file.
Per default everyone is Depositor. If you add the User or Group and set to "no Access", they won't be able to send mail.